# django foreign key conditional

Tags: django, model

Below is my models.

```
class DoneType (AbstractTimeStamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)

class Done (AbstractTimeStamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    done_type = models.ForeignKey(DoneType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

> >
>   One user can have many DONE models. And DONE models can have many DONE_TYPE models.
>   
> However, this is only possible if USER in the DONE model is the same as USER in the DONE_TYPE model.
>   How do I implement this?

Comment: You don't need the `user` field in in `DoneType` model.

Comment: @art06 is right. You are denormalizing your relational schema by having a redundant field. This might sometimes be desirable for performance reasons but I highly doubt that this is the case for you. If you need to access the `user` field in a `DoneType` instance you can always use `done_type.done.user`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It would make more sense to make `DoneType.user` inherit it's `ForeignKey` from `Done` instead, and then you could call it by `done_type.user.user`.**

That way, you won't even need to do any comparisons, so no extra database hit is required *(faster too)*.

But if you wanted to compare the 2 fields, you would do is something like this in your views...

Assume `done = Done.objects.get(id=1)` and `done_type = DoneType.objects.get(id=1)`

```
if done.user == done_type.user:
    # do something
```

But comparing this like that is a bad idea.

Comment: Doing this check in the view code is a very bad suggestion. There might be several points in code where you create `Done`/`DoneType` instances and your suggestion requires _not forgetting_ to add that comparison in any of those places. It would be much better to recommend overriding the `save()` method of one of the models to implement this as a constraint.

Comment: Yeah, like I suggested, it's a bad idea. But the question was how to compare them, so with that in mind I answered correctly. **Then, I showed him a better method, because with that method you don't even have to do the check at all *(by making the DoneType related by ForeignKey to Done, instead of User again)*.** That way there would be no need to override the `.save()` method either, so no comparison necessary... At least with the info he's given us so far. SInce some people have a problem reading the whole post, I guess I'll put that bit first instead.